# HELP Lyx command \appendix

Tags: lyx, appendices

for my thesis i decided to improve my work inserting directly in Lyx the command "\appendix" but i don't understand how to end this part. 
I would like to insert an Appendix between two different chapters but if i use this command everything i'll write after that will be inside the Appendix without the possibility to come back to a "normal chapter".
Could someone help me?
Could someone explain me how to end the \appendix part?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `appendix` package:

```
\documentclass{book} % or report or ...
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
text
\begin{subappendices}
\section{An appendix}
text
\section{Another appendix}
text
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Second}
text
\end{document}
```

Read the manual (`> texdoc appendix`) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get an error message "LaTeX Error: Environment subappendixes undefined."

Comment: @TanjaSantner My apologies, I made a typo. It should be `\begin{subappendices}` and `\end{subappendices}`. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This new command `\noappendix` should work, at least with a manual set up.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\noappendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{2}% <--manually insert the number of chapters before \appendix was used
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\chaptername}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@arabic\c@chapter}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering my question. I tried what you told me to do, but the chapter after my "Appendix" still still appears as an appendix.

Comment: Did you put the code on preamble and then `\noappendix` just before start the new chapter?